# Expo release channels and project folder

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using Expo’s managed workflow. My app uses google authentication to sign in. During development I was using the Expo client for android and as per the docs I used 'Expo.Google' to achieve google authentication and it worked as intended.

After developing the app, I built a staging version of my app (standalone app) by typing 'expo build:android -t apk --release-channel staging-v1' in my project directory. After the build was finished, I downloaded and installed the apk on my android phone. Only then I realized that I didn’t change 'Expo.Google' to 'GoogleSignIn' which is required for standalone apps.

I can change that in my project files and then publish it to the staging-v1 channel. I think this would make google authentication work in the standalone app but it would also change my project files and then it won’t work in the Expo client. So, do I need to create and maintain two different project folders which would basically be the same except for the google authentication part? In general, how should I manage the channels and the corresponding project files?